# Deploy JasperServer in GlassFish

Tags: oracle, glassfish, oracle-xe, jasperserver

I've been trying to deploy jasperserver 4 in glassfish 3 and using oracle 10g express edition for repository. I've tried following the install guide and making some changes since the install guide doesn't actually cover glassfish and oracle db that much.

Below is the log file I get when running the auto install script "js-install-ce.bat"

Edited: Apr 26, 2011

I updated the OracleUnicodeDialect and used org.hiberntate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect. Now I'm getting a different error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Running JasperReports Server install script at 2011-04-26_08-33 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[minimal] 
Running install-minimal-ce Ant task 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Buildfile: C:\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin\buildomatic\build.xml
     [echo] Filtering properties (cleaning out blank spaces)

set-minimal-mode:

gen-config:
     [echo] Regen config files if they have already been cleaned:
     [echo] currentConf= C:/jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin/buildomatic/build_conf/default

test-ce-all-props:
     [echo] Checking properties:
     [echo]   appServerType=glassfish2
     [echo]   appServerDir=c:\glassfish3\glassfish
     [echo]   dbType=oracle
     [echo]   dbHost=localhost
     [echo]   dbUsername=jasperserver
     [echo]   dbPassword=**********
     [echo]   dbPort=1521
     [echo]   js.dbName=jasperserver
     [echo]   sugarcrm.dbName=sugarcrm
     [echo]   foodmart.dbName=foodmart
     [echo]   webAppNameCE=jasperserver

check-dbtype-ce:

test-appServerType-ce:

do-pre-install-test:
     [echo] Checking DBMS host and port:
     [echo]   Host localhost is OK
     [echo]   Port 1521 is OK
     [echo] Validating administrative database connection at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe. Phase: [test]
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Connection OK
     [echo] Validating JasperServer database connection at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe. Phase: [test]
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Connection OK
     [echo] Validating FoodMart database connection at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe. Phase: [test]
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Database doesn't exist. Treating problem with JDBC connection as noncritical. Proceeding to next step
     [echo] Validating SugarCRM database connection at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe. Phase: [test]
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Database doesn't exist. Treating problem with JDBC connection as noncritical. Proceeding to next step

pre-install-test-ce:

recreate-js-db-normal:
     [echo] Validating JasperServer database connection at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe. Phase: [before]
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Connection OK
    [input] Database [jasperserver] already exists. Drop it and create new? WARNING: All existing data will be lost! This operation may not be rolled back. Enter 'y' to recreate or 'n' to skip this step. Default is 'n' (y, [n])
     [echo] Filtering properties (cleaning out blank spaces)

drop-js-db:
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin\buildomatic\build_conf\default\killSession.sql
      [sql] 0 rows affected
      [sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
[advanced-sql] Executing commands
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Filtering properties (cleaning out blank spaces)

create-js-db:
[advanced-sql] Executing commands
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 2 of 2 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Validating JasperServer database connection at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe. Phase: [after]
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Connection OK

recreate-js-db:

fill-js-ce-db-minimal:
     [echo] Filtering properties (cleaning out blank spaces)

init-js-db-ce:
[advanced-sql] Executing resource: C:\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin\buildomatic\install_resources\sql\oracle\quartz.ddl
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 1 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 1 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 1 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 1 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 1 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 0 rows affected
[advanced-sql] 32 of 32 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Filtering properties (cleaning out blank spaces)

import-minimal-ce:
     [echo]  
     [echo] Property values (in install.xml): 
     [echo]  archiveArg = --input-zip=C:/jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin/buildomatic/install_resources/export/js-catalog-minimal-ce.zip
     [echo]  dbType = oracle
     [echo]  jdbcJar = ojdbc5-11.2.0.jar
     [echo]  currentConf = C:/jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin/buildomatic/build_conf/default
     [echo]  importExportConfig = C:/jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin/buildomatic/conf_source/ieCe
     [echo]  
     [echo] Validating JasperServer database connection at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe. Phase: [test]
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
[select-sql] Executing commands
[select-sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Connection OK
     [java] Creating ActionModelService object.
     [java] Creating action model infrastructure.
     [java] 2011-04-26 20:35:05,359  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
     [java] 2011-04-26 20:35:05,359 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
     [java] 
     [java] org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:630)
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessExc2011-04-26 20:35:05,422 ERROR BaseExportImportCommand:45 - org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
     [java] eption(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1055)
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1048)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.tenant.service.impl.TenantServiceImpl.getRepoTenant(TenantServiceImpl.java:82)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.tenant.service.impl.TenantServiceImpl.getTenant(TenantServiceImpl.java:178)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     [java]     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
     [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
     [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
     [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
     [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
     [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
     [java]     at $Proxy5.getTenant(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.modules.mt.TenantImporter.process(TenantImporter.java:59)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.modules.mt.TenantImporter.process(TenantImporter.java:48)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImporterImpl.process(ImporterImpl.java:146)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImporterImpl.performImport(ImporterImpl.java:95)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImportCommandImpl.process(ImportCommandImpl.java:57)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.BaseExportImportCommand.process(BaseExportImportCommand.java:88)
     [java]     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImportCommand.main(ImportCommand.java:43)
     [java] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
     [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1065)
     [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
     [java]     ... 23 more
     [java] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
     [java] 
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
     [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
     [java]     ... 30 more

BUILD FAILED
C:\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin\buildomatic\bin\db-common.xml:742: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin\buildomatic\bin\import-export.xml:259: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0-bin\buildomatic\bin\import-export.xml:152: Java returned: -1

Total time: 1 minute 6 seconds
Checking Ant return code: OK 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I noticed that aside from getting the org.springframework error, I also get an error about a table not existing but it doesn't say which table.

Comment: It's looks like your error is Dialect class not found: com.jaspersoft.ji.hibernate.dialect.OracleUnicodeDialec There are a few links on jasper talking about it

Comment: Updated my original post with the new error after using a different Dialect.

Comment: Have you looked in the glassfish server.log file for additional info? Also, if you crank up the logging for hibernate you can see the query it's trying to execute.

Comment: I'm getting the same org.springframework error when trying to deploy on glassfish and mysql.

Comment: Did you read this, right?      "[echo] Connection OK
    [input] Database [jasperserver] already exists. Drop it and create new? WARNING: All existing data will be lost! This operation may not be rolled back. Enter 'y' to recreate or 'n' to skip this step. Default is 'n' (y, [n])
     [echo] Filtering properties (cleaning out blank spaces)". Maybe the db was not correctly build!